# What is pizza sauce?

Tags: sauce

I am making a dip that requires 'pizza sauce'. The store doesn't sell anything called 'pizza sauce' that I could find. Instead, I got plain tomato sauce. What do I need to add to it to make it 'pizza sauce'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pizza sauce is, presumably, whatever tomato-based sauce you'd put on a pizza. Those tend to be essentially like smooth (not chunky), lightly seasoned spaghetti sauce. If by "plain tomato sauce" you mean a jar of tomato sauce for spaghetti, you're probably in good shape. If you mean a can of pure tomato sauce, with no other ingredients, you'll probably want to add some seasoning. Basil and oregano are good bets for herbs; garlic and onion are also common, and perhaps crushed red pepper if you want a little kick.

If you're looking for a real recipe, [this isn't a recipe request site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq), but search engines will serve you well.

Comment: As for the tomatoes, you can start with pre-sauced sauce, paste, stewed tomatoes, or fresh.  One recipe I've seen has the tomatoes cooked on a hot grill, then mashed into the pizza with herbs.  I often use stewed/canned tomatoes, and mash them into something more sauce-like while reducing them.  The closer to fresh, the better they taste!

Answer (score 2):

In my family pizza sauce it just fresh garden tomatoes simmered for a few hours or more with a good drizzle of nice olive oil

I leave the pot lid on until the tomatoes have fully rendered down and are just lightly bubbling

Add fresh chopped herbs when serving or adding to a dish i.e. smearing on pizza base

Answer (score 2):

Pizza sauce is typically much thicker than the tomato sauce you would put on pasta and more heavily seasoned. The idea is that you are spreading a thin layer of the sauce over a large area, so a thinner sauce won't work and/or might lose too much liquid as you bake your pizza. Don Pepino pizza sauce is great, assuming you can get it where you live. If you have a jar of commercial pasta sauce around, I would add basil, oregano, and garlic to it. Then, add a good bit of tomato paste to make it thicker.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some italian seasonings to the tomato sauce and reduce it a bit.  Garlic, Parsely, Basil, Oregano, pepper, salt...etc...touch of olive oil..

Answer (score 1):

Most grocery stores carry *Pizza Sauce*. I know for certain I have purchased a [*Ragù* variant](http://www.ragu.com/product/detail/89652/homemade-style) at [Publix](http://www.publix.com/), [Walmart](http://www.walmart.com/), [Sweetbay](http://www.sweetbaysupermarket.com/) and [Meijer](http://www.meijer.com/) on separate occasions. It typically comes in a much smaller glass jar than that of *spaghetti* sauce. I've seen it shelved either with the pasta sauces, canned tomatoes or in a bakery section next to pizza doughs.

Or you can just make your own, as I tend to do most of the time these days.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

at home I just used tomato paste, and added something simple, ex. salt

Comment: While this can work for a pizza, I don't know if it would work in a recipe that expects something more seasoned.